# How to use the MediaController

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to integrate a MediaController on top of a MediaPlayer. 
The controller is displayed all right, but its buttons are disabled, and the progress slider does not respond properly.

I found very little documentation about it and I still don't understand how to use it. 
This is very important and urgent for me. 
Can anyone who has dealt with it before explain how it works?

Thanks, 
Eyal

Comment: can u put some code on how you are integrating them

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Api demos under your SDK directory. There is an example in there.